# Is it possible in Python to make a one-liner with multiple IF and OR after RETURN statement?

Tags: python, return, conditional-statements

I hope it's pretty clear what I wanna do with this function:

```
def this_one_operator(math_operator, num1, num2):
    return num1 * num2 if operator == "*" \
        or num1 / num2 if operator == "/" \
        or num1 + num2 if operator == "+" \
        or num1 - num2 if operator == "-"
```

Obviously, it doesn't work (SyntaxError: invalid syntax).

Sorry if I duplicate the question. I did my best to find here how to deal with that problem. Also, I appreciate any suggestion how to edit the question if it's not accurate.

Thanks.

Comment: `else`, not `or`, and you need a default case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python has a `value if condition else default` [ternary operation,](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html?highlight=ternary#is-there-an-equivalent-of-c-s-ternary-operator) which you could stack for this result. However, it's not very compact, and not very pythonic to be doing what you seem to want to do.

Instead, you might try:

```
import operator 

def binary_op(op, lopd, ropd):
    return { '/' : operator.floordiv,
             '*' : operator.mul,
             '+' : operator.add,
             '-' : operator.sub,
             '%' : operator.mod }[op](lopd, ropd)
```

Comment: I supposed there was some stuff like this for math operators. Thanks. It works.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but it's ugly.

```
return (x * y if operator == "*" else
        x / y if operator == "/" else
        x + y if operator == "+" else
        x - y if operator == "-" else
        None)
```

Alternatively:

```
import operator
OPERATORS = {
    '*': operator.mul,
    '/': operator.truediv,
    '+': operator.add,
    '-': operator.sub,
}

return OPERATOR[op](x, y)
```

Comment: Thank you. Your first one clarified Python's logic and syntax for me.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't pretty, but it works:

```
def this_one_operator(math_operator, num1, num2):
    return (operator == "/")*(num1/num2) + \
           (operator == "+")*(num1+num2) + \
           (operator == "-")*(num1-num2) + \
           (operator == "*")*(num1*num2)
```

The reason this works is that the boolean statements are equal to either 0 or 1, so multiplying them by the correct expression and summing the correct total will yield the right result.

Edit: Actually, this doesn't work as others have pointed out because the division operation may result in an undefined result.

Comment: But now you can't do `this_one_operator('+', 0, 0)`

Comment: It doesn't work: `this_one_operator('+', 5, 0)` should return 5 but it raises an exception...

Comment: Probably a divide-by-zero error due to computing something that shouldn't be computed.